# Multiple libgdx applications at once

Tags: java, libgdx

My game has a lot of text onscreen as a debug purpose and I need much more text on screen to help me. Here is an image of the debug text on screen. 
[image]

When I run the application, this is what appears. However what I would like to happen (for debugging) is for another window to pop up. By window I mean like another libgdx application running alongside the game application. And in this second window I want to have all the debug text lay there so that I can see the game for how it will look while it's running without all the debug junk. Any help is extremely appreciated.

Comment: You could have a .txt file, and write the console/debugging information to the file. But I don't think you are able to look at a file as a program is reading/writing to it. Having a second frame (referring back to swing here) is generally bad practice., so you might not want to approach this method. If all-else fails, you can always make the window/frame smaller (If you didn't hard code everything, it should be pretty straight forward), so you can see the console.

Comment: @WyattLowery I like things color coded thats why i need the text this is more a convenience question than anything thank you tho!

Comment: More of an alternative solution than the one you've proposed, but can you just have a simple checkbox somewhere that you can check/uncheck to turn debugging on or off? I think I would prefer that to swapping screens, myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a [Window](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/Window.html) pop up when you want to view debug information. It is draggable, which means you can move it around, and you can make is semi transparent if you want to see through it. The window can pop up upon a double click (for example) on your stage. Your `Stage` code would look roughly like this:

```
public class MyStage extends Stage {
    private boolean debug = false;
    private Window debugWindow = new DebugWindow(); // your customized Window that contains the debug info 
    public MyStage(...) {
        addListener(new ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
                if (getTapCount() >= 2) { // i.e., double click
                    debug = !debug;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void act() {
        // ...
        if (debug && debugWindow.getStage() != this) {
            addActor(debugWindow); // This will add the debug window to your stage, making the debug info visible
        }
        else if (!debug && debugWindow.getStage() == this) {
            debugWindow.remove(); // When you want the debug window out of the way
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is this window class? are you saying to override the window class and it will display another window elsewhere?

Comment: Take a look at the link I put up. It explains the purpose and capabilities of the `Window` class. Basically, it resembles the familiar Window entities used in OS's. Look [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S71NpGlP8hk) for a neat video tutorial on the subject. Yes, extending `Window` for your specific needs will be the best way to go in my opinion.